# FB.Connect.streamPublish error?

Tags: facebook, stream, publishing

Does anybody here know if Facebook is deprecating the existing JS api.  The pubblishing pop-up just started showing up blank as of yesterday.  It was working fine three days ago.  I haven't changed my code.

Thanks!  Trying to learn information from Facebook itself is an exercise in futility.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not, I implemented that today on:

http://www.faboccasion.com/fbsignin.php